# facebook4j facebook.getPosts returns no elements

Tags: java, facebook, facebook4j

When my user is a tester I can get their posts with no trouble but when the user is not no posts are returned.  The code is in different places in the application.  Here is some of the code

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
facebook.setOAuthAppId(FBConnection.FB_APP_ID, FBConnection.FB_APP_SECRET);
String commaSeparetedPermissions = "email,publish_stream,user_posts";
facebook.setOAuthPermissions(commaSeparetedPermissions);
String authFB = facebook.getOAuthAuthorizationURL(FBConnection.REDIRECT_URI);

...

name = facebook.getMe().getName();
Reading r = new Reading().fields("message", "picture");
ResponseList<Post> posts = facebook.getPosts(r);
```

In other code I successfully obtain an extended token which calculates to about 2 months.  In the user's facebook settings->apps->thisapp->timelineposts->your posts is ticked.

However the posts object has null count and zero elements.

I'm at a loss to understand why.

Comment: Have you submitted your app for review to get the permissions approved? And `publish_stream` doesn’t even exist any more.

Comment: Ok, thanks I appreciate your advice.  I saw publish_stream in one of the facebook4j site examples.  The developer console does seems to say some Facebook integrations require approval, is that the same as "submitting the app for review", presumably then getposts requires this approval.  Is everything I need to know under  Platform Policy and Review Guidelines, or are their any tips, pitfalls etc you could share.  Thank you.

Comment: If the app (website say) is only ever going to just present parts of selected FB posts inside the website from ONLY THE ONE FB user, the owner of the rest of the website content, is there anything that technically prevents or policy prohibits that user from being a tester/developer or even being the app owner/developer themselves and therefore never submitting the app for formal review?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: sorry I missed that.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I appreciate it.  Not sure where and if its worth a discussion, but it strikes me it would be good if either FB or Facebook4j respond with some kind of http error code / Exception when authority is lacking as against there is no data.